# Composite index is not getting registered. It is struck in ENABLED status forever

Tags: janusgraph

I'm running janusgraph with cassandra and ES as backend. Following is my script used in building the composite index.

```
JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement()
def addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(JanusGraphManagement mgmt, String keyName, Class keyType, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality cardinalityType) {
    if (!mgmt.containsPropertyKey(keyName)) mgmt.makePropertyKey(keyName).dataType(keyType).cardinality(cardinalityType).make()
}
vertexCompositeIndexName = "vertex_data_composite"

addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "vertex_id", String.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "tenant", String.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "entity", String.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "entity_type", String.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "first_seen_at", Long.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "first_seen_source", String.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)
addPropertyKeyIfNotExists(mgmt, "last_seen_at", Long.class, org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE)

vertexId = mgmt.getPropertyKey("vertex_id")
tenant = mgmt.getPropertyKey("tenant")
entity = mgmt.getPropertyKey("entity")
entityType = mgmt.getPropertyKey("entity_type")
firstSeenAt = mgmt.getPropertyKey("first_seen_at")
firstSeenSource = mgmt.getPropertyKey("first_seen_source")
lastSeenAt = mgmt.getPropertyKey("last_seen_at")
if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex(vertexCompositeIndexName)) {
    mgmt.buildIndex(vertexCompositeIndexName, Vertex.class).
        addKey(vertexId).
        addKey(tenant).
        addKey(entity).
        addKey(firstSeenSource).
        addKey(entityType).
        addKey(firstSeenAt).
        addKey(lastSeenAt).
        buildCompositeIndex()
}


println(mgmt.printSchema())
mgmt.commit()
mgmt.close()
graph.close()

graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties")
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, vertexCompositeIndexName).call()
```

It has been more than an hour and still the composite index status is in ENABLED. It never became REGISTERED.

```
gremlin> mgmt.printSchema()
==>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Graph Index (Vertex)           | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vertex_data_composite          | Composite   | false     | internalindex  | vertex_id:    ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | tenant:       ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | entity:       ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | first_seen_source:    ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | entity_type:    ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | first_seen_at:    ENABLED |
                               |             |           |                | last_seen_at:    ENABLED |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I see the following in my logs

```
jce-janusgraph   | 7953215 [gremlin-server-worker-1] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher  - Some key(s) on index vertex_data_composite do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: entity_type=ENABLED,vertex_id=ENABLED,first_seen_at=ENABLED,first_seen_source=ENABLED,last_seen_at=ENABLED,tenant=ENABLED,entity=ENABLED
jce-janusgraph   | 7953216 [gremlin-server-worker-1] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.GraphIndexStatusWatcher  - Timed out (PT1M) while waiting for index vertex_data_composite to converge on status(es) [REGISTERED]
```

Composite index not used while querying.

```
gremlin> g.V().has("vertex_id","ddd").profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
JanusGraphStep([],[vertex_id.eq(ddd)])                                                        49.819   100.00
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                  15.133
  constructGraphCentricQuery                                                                   0.074
  GraphCentricQuery                                                                           19.326
    \_condition=(vertex_id = ddd)
    \_orders=[]
    \_isFitted=false
    \_isOrdered=true
    \_query=[]
    scan                                                                                      17.445
    \_query=[]
    \_fullscan=true
    \_condition=VERTEX
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -          49.819        -
```

We see following in the logs

```
jce-janusgraph   | 339186 [gremlin-server-session-1] WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(vertex_id = ddd)]. For better performance, use indexes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JanusGraph index lifecycle](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-lifecycle/) you can see that your index is already `ENABLED` and can be used. You don't need to wait for the index to be `REGISTERED` in this particular case.
Normally index transition in the following order:

`INSTALLED` - The index is installed in the system but not yet registered with all instances in the cluster.
`REGISTERED` - The index is registered with all instances in the cluster but not (yet) enabled.
`ENABLED` - The index is enabled and in use.
`DISABLED` - The index is disabled and no longer in use.

Usually after your created the index it becomes `INSTALLED`, then you wait until all JanusGraph nodes pick up the newly created index and it changes the status to `REGISTERED`. As soon as it is `REGISTERED` (meaning all JanusGraph nodes know about it) you can enable the index or start `REINDEX` process which automatically enables the index after reindex is finished.
So, why your index changed the status to `ENABLED` immediately instead of transitioning from state to state? That's because JanusGraph has a special optimization which enables newly created indexes immediately if all it's keys were created in the same transaction. In your situation all properties were created in the same transaction (most likely). Thus, your index is now `ENABLED`. You don't need to do anything else because your index is already in use.

P.S. As a side topic, not directly related to this use-case but related to the issue when the index cannot change it's state from `INSTALLED` to `REGISTERED` you can checkout the [following suggestions](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/3195#discussioncomment-3595012).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. The main reason why I was worried about this is because the composite index which I created is not being used while querying.

Comment: So in my case I have a composite index(cassandra) and a mixed index(ES). The composite index which I created is not being used while doing bulk loading and also during querying. Data loading/ querying is fine with ES but not with composite index.

Comment: As you can see the composite index is not getting used and this is resulting in full table scans.

Comment: @Abhiram composite index requires all keys to be presented in the query unlike mixed index which doesn't have this constraint.
In your situation you added the next keys: .addKey(vertexId).addKey(tenant).addKey(entity).addKey(firstSeenSource).addKey(entityType).addKey(firstSeenAt).addKey(lastSeenAt).

All of the must be in the query for composite index to be used. Otherwise, you should use mixed index for partial index queries.

See the constrains (number `3`) explained here: https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/#composite-versus-mixed-indexes